# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate inside nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to update the type, key and values in the 'fields' array if the componentId and the wfInstanceId id matches.

This is the document that i need to do so.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5af"
    },
    "wfInstanceId": "0111",
    "workflowId": "ash3",
    "folderURL": "ash3",
    "teamName": "teamName",
    "dataStream": [
        {
            "componentInstanceId": "componentInstanceId1",
            "componentId": "componentId1",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5b0"
            },
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "value1",
                    "key": "key",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5b1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "value2",
                    "key": "key1",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5b1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "componentInstanceId": "componentInstanceId2",
            "componentId": "componentId22",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5b0"
            },
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "value1",
                    "key": "key",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5b1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "value2",
                    "key": "key2",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "586b6d756937c22f207dd5b1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": "38f356f0-d196-11e6-b0b9-3956ed7f36f0",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I tried this like this, Also i tried $set over $push which is also doesn't work.

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate( {'wfInstanceId': '0111', 'dataStream.componentId': 'componentId1'}, {$push : { 'dataStream.fields.$.key' : 'sdsdds' }}, { upsert: true }, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log('error occured' + err);
                }
                console.info("succesfully saved");
                resolve (data);
            });
```

As they describe in this [DOC](https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays) it shouldbe working for update method that is also didn't work for me. Any help will be really appreciated to overcome this issue i'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using **$** operator it updates only the **first** matched array element in each document.

As of now it is not possible in mongoose to directly update all array elements.

You can do this in your case:

```
db.collection.find({'wfInstanceId': '0111', 'dataStream.componentId': 'componentId1'})
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.datastream.forEach(function (datastream) {
      if (dataStream.componentId === componentId1) {
        dataStream.fields.forEach(function(fields){
         // you can also write condition for matching condition in field
           dataStream.fields.key="";
           dataStream.fields.value="";
           dataStream.fields.type="";
         }
      }
    });
    db.collection.save(doc);
  });
```

It is normal javascript code. I think it's clearer for mongo newbies.

Comment: it says Model.save is not a function

Comment: in mongoose do this doc.save(); as save method is in the doc

Comment: Anybody knows how to do this using $push or $set ?